# In the most simplest explanation possible how to convert an array to min and max heaps in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, heapsort

So recently i learned about heaps and iam really struggling to find an easy algo to convert an array to max and min heap in C++. My approach is as follows (for max heap) if you have an array of n size, use the formula
k=(n-1)/2 -1.We will start from index k and traverse backwards. From k till index 1 (skipping index 0 so as to accomodate the left child 2i and right child 2i+1 indexes), we will compare each node with its children if its lesser than both.In case this condition is true we will check for second condition that which child is greater of the two and then swap that child with the parent. It's all good till this point but suppose we are heapifying an array of size 7 that looks like this

```
index   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
element   5 6 8 1 9 2
```

In this method index 2 its children 4 and 5, index 1 and its children 2 and 3 are taken care of but what will happen of index 6.

I looked up geeksforgeeks.com and also checked youtube and other websites but couldnt find anything helpful.

Edit: Here is my approach can you guys check this for errors

```
void a_buildHeap(int arr[],int n)
{
    int swaps{};
    int comps{};
    for (int i = n/2; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int lc = 2*i;
        int rc = 2*i + 1;
        if (arr[i] < arr[lc] && arr[i] < arr[rc])
        {
            comps++;
            if (lc > rc)
            {
                swap(arr[i], arr[lc]);
                swaps++;
            }
            else if (rc > lc)
            {
                swap(arr[i], arr[rc]);
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Total swaps: " << swaps << " "<<endl;
    cout << "Total comaprisons: " << comps << endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap. And geekforgeeks like leetcode are better avoided.

Comment: geeksforgeeks.com:  you will never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy. We must be cautious.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to skip index 0. `Left = Index * 2 + 1` and `Right = Index * 2 + 2` can access the child elements too.

I solve this problem recursively. Start at the root element and first call the same function (recursively) on the left and right child element if they exist (check for out of bound here).

Now check which of the 3 elements is the largest/smallest (again you need to check if they exist first). Root, left or right. If Root is largest/smallest don't do anything. If it is left or right then swap the elements.

Finally if you did a swap it is important to call the recursive function on the swapped child position again.

Now you should end up with the solution.

Edit:

> `for (int i = n/2; i >= 1; i--)`

This for loops doesn't work in all cases. In some cases you either will miss a potential swap or you get out of bounds. So you still need to check for that. Also simply traversing once through the tree will not be enough to sort it correctly.

> `if (arr[i] < arr[lc] && arr[i] < arr[rc])`

This if statement is wrong. You check if the left and the right child are larger when actually only one of the need to be larger.

Next you check if the left or right child is larger. What will you do if they are both the same size?

Finally your approach of traversing backwards will only work in certain cases and not in all cases. You should try to use a debugger or just get a pen and paper and try to visualize what will happen if run your code.

Comment: I just have one concern regarding your approach the right child and left child wont they have different formulas, or was it a typo. Rest of your approach is great.

Comment: You're right. It was a typo.

Comment: can you check my code for errors?